# Multiple Row to single row query result

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    'XXXXXXXXXXX',
    APP_ID,
    COND_ID,
    GMTDATE,
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE COND_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
```

Above query has more then 100,000 data. I want a single row result where has It is giving multiple row because it take more than a second to process the data.

AS result is: (Two row )

```
XXXXXXXXXXX    APP_ID      COND_ID         GMTDATE 
XXXXXXXXXXX    11091000000  20170601010765  06-JUN-17 
XXXXXXXXXXX    11091000000  20170601010765  06-JUN-17
```

Desired result is: (One row)

```
XXXXXXXXXXX    APP_ID      COND_ID         GMTDATE
XXXXXXXXXXX    11091000000  20170601010765  06-JUN-17
```

Comment: Your sample table data is hard to read.  Can you edit your question and make it more clear?

Comment: You shouldn't be getting those two rows with `DISTINCT` if the data in all columns really be the same.  I'm not sure what more I can say here.

Comment: So as DISTINCT is used, So it should give one row data.. Table has huge data.. So it take more than 2-3 seconds to process the data.. and So it generate a row for every second. I mean sometime 2 row, sometime 3 row.

Comment: try group by XXXXXXXXXXX this

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
'XXXXXXXXXXX',
APP_ID,
COND_ID,
GMTDATE,
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE COND_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4 ;    --I have assumed 'XXXXXXXXXXX' is a column name
```

Comment: yes XXXXXXXXXXX is column name.. What GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4? Do you means GROUP BY 'XXXXXXXXXXX',
APP_ID,
COND_ID,
GMTDATE  It still give the same result.

Comment: @ShaktiPravesh, the use of distinct is redundant. you may remove it. and i also assume you put 'XXXXXXXXXXX' without the quotes(''). and yes, 1,2,3,4 means those columns